# If a data structure is foldable, is it a monoid?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads, monoids

Obviously, if a data structure is a monoid, it's foldable, but is it safe to say if a data structure is foldable, it's a monoid?

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Foldable

If a data structure is foldable, is it a monoid?

Comment: `Data.List.NonEmpty` are `foldable` but not a `monoid` since you have drop the zero element. Btw, `Alternative` is a `monoid` but not `foldable`

Comment: A foldable data structure is generally a container, such as list or set. Saying this is foldable means that you can accumulate all its contents into a single value by providing some function to add one of the values to the accumulator. If the value type is a monoid then this function can be `mappend`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LuisMorillo Thanks but, I thought every List is a monoid.

Comment: @PaulJohnson `mappend ` as the binary operator? and yes. Monoids = binary operator(including the specific identity element such as Zero for addition)  + flat structure(associative). That's what  I meant.

Comment: @bayesian-study A monoid is a data structure which have a binary (associative) operation _and_ a neutral element (a.k.a. zero element). So every list can be concatenated, giving you the binary operation. But `List.NonEmpty` has no zero element therefore it can't be a monoid. The proper TypeClass for `List.NonEmpty` is `Semigroup` ;)

Comment: What does "if a data structure is a monoid, it's foldable" even mean? For example, `()` is a pretty trivial monoid, but I can't think of a sensible interpretation of "`()` is foldable" -- it doesn't even have the right kind. (Going the other way, with a bit of work I think I could interpret things; e.g. "`Foldable f` implies `Monoid (f a)`" is a sensible (but wrong) claim that bridges the kind mismatch.)

Answer (score 21):

Your claim "if a data structure is a `Monoid` then it is `Foldable`" is not reasonably true.  For example:

```hs
newtype ActionList a = ActionList (IO [a])

instance Monoid (ActionList a) where
    mempty = ActionList (return [])
    ActionList a `mappend` ActionList b = ActionList (liftA2 (++) a b)
```

This is a perfectly good monoid.  But because all of its values are under `IO`, you can't observe any of them from `Foldable`.  The only `Foldable` instance would be the one that always returns empty (technically this would be valid because `foldMap` doesn't really have any laws about its validity, but it would hard to say that this is a good instance with a straight face).

The converse, which you are asking about, is also not true.  For example:

```hs
data TwoThings a = TwoThings a a
```

This is foldable:

```hs
instance Foldable TwoThings where
    foldMap f (TwoThings x y) = f x <> f y
```

However, if something is both a `Foldable` and a `Monoid` in any related way, I would expect the following homomorphism laws to hold:

```hs
foldMap f mempty = mempty
foldMap f (a <> b) = foldMap f a <> foldMap f b
```

And we can't get these laws to hold for `TwoThings`.  Notice that `foldMap (:[]) a` for `TwoThings` always has two elements.  But then the second law has two elements on the left and four on the right.  But the laws are not required to find a counterexample, as [dfeuer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828757/33796) shows.

Comment: Thanks, >because all of its values are under IO, you can't observe any of them from Foldable< but there is IO monoid,  amd I thought IO monoid is definitely foldable http://www.haskellforall.com/2018/02/the-wizard-monoid.html isn't it.

Comment: @bayesian-study Why do you think `IO` is a foldable? If it were a foldable, we would have `toList (getChar) :: [Char]` -- what would be the resulting list? Note that this not an IO value, so evaluating that performs no IO, and always produces the same constant string. That string would be a completely arbitrary string.

Comment: @bayesian-study You don't even need `IO` to not be `Foldable`.  Functions suffice. There exists `instance (Monoid b) => Monoid (a -> b)`, but you cannot usefully implement `instance Foldable ((->) a)`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's something `Foldable` (even `Traversable`) that has no hope of being a `Monoid`:

```hs
{-# language EmptyCase #-}

data F a

instance Foldable F where
  foldMap _ t = case t of
  -- or, = mempty
instance Traversable F where
  traverse _ t = case t of
  -- or, = pure $ case t of

instance Semigroup (F a) where
  -- the only option
  x <> _ = x

instance Monoid (F a) where
  mempty = ????
```

Comment: Lol, It's the `V1` type!

Comment: @DannyuNDos, indeed.